# Why the sequence of a field changes when saved in Odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I have a form view for `sale.order.line` model and have created a field (sequence field) called `' niu '` which increases its value automatically.

For each product type stockable you add to the form which is working fine But I have a problem because when you add a product stackable the value increases, but when I press the 'Save ' button automatically changes the sequence.

**See below attached Images :**

[image]

[image]

This is the ' niu ' field and sale.order.line method within the model:

```
niu = fields.Char(string="NIU", compute="_niu_validation", readonly=True, store=True)

@api.depends('product_id.product_tmpl_id.type')
def _niu_validation(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.product_id.product_tmpl_id.type == 'product' and not rec.niu:
                rec.niu = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('sale.order.line')
```

What can I do to make the sequence is not changed and the initial number is established ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `next_by_code()` method generate value based on [nextval() function of PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-sequence.html).

You called `next_by_code()` method of `ir.sequence` object. In this method calls method `_next()`. Let's see body:

```
def _next(self):
    if self.sequence_id.implementation == 'standard':
        number_next = _select_nextval(self.env.cr, 'ir_sequence_%03d_%03d' % (self.sequence_id.id, self.id))
    else:
        number_next = _update_nogap(self, self.sequence_id.number_increment)

    return self.sequence_id.get_next_char(number_next)
```

The new value is generated using **number_next**. In your case `_select_nextval` will be called:

```
def _select_nextval(cr, seq_name):
    cr.execute("SELECT nextval('%s')" % seq_name)

    return cr.fetchone()
```

As you can see function `nextval` is called in query.

**How it works.**

OpenERP will call method `_niu_validation` when you add some `sale.order.line` in form. It is because object(each line) will calculate value for your field `niu`. In your method it is called by `next_by_code`. It means that **before save**(just for GUI / tree view) postgreSQL changed sequences. When you click on *Save* button(in header) the system calls `_niu_validation` again.

To sum up.
Odoo doesn't apply changes in tree view until you click *Save*. You make some changes in `tree view` and at the same time sequences will be changed  in db(because you calculate value for column `NIU`). But the lines are not saved in db.

You can check how it works here: `path_to_odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_sequence.py`

*What can you do to make the sequence not changed?*

You can remove method `_niu_validation`, override method `create` of `sale.order.line` and calculate value for field when your line is stored.
But in this case user will not see new values for column 'on fly'.

Hope this helps you.

One more thing that is worth thinking about(if you want to use your approach). Imagine that several people are working on one order at the same time.

Comment: Hello , with respect to paragraph: You can remove method _niu_validation, override method create of sale.order.line and calculate value for field when your line is stored. But in this case user will not see new values for column 'on fly'.

How can I make creating method to calculate the value of the field when stored?

I overwrote _niu_validation by the method create ( self )

@api.model
    def create(self):
  for recordset in self:
   if rec.product_id.product_tmpl_id.type == 'product' and not rec.niu:
        rec.niu = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('sale.order.line')

Comment: In your model: `niu = fields.Char(string="NIU", readonly=True) @api.model def create(self, vals): vals[u'niu'] = #write here any logic... return super(NameYourClass, self).create(vals)`

Comment: In my model I put the following, but does not create the sequence when I press the save button . Why does this happen ?

    @api.model 
    def create(self, vals):
        for rec in self:
            if rec.product_id.product_tmpl_id.type == 'product' and not rec.niu:
                vals[u'niu'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('sale.order.line')
            return super(SaleOrderLine, self).create(vals)

Comment: @beriliox Name for invoices in sales work in a similar way(`sale.order` object of Odoo). For more understanding  you can see `path_to_odoo/addons/sale/sale.py`.

Comment: @beriliox See source of other applications. This is the only way to understand how the system works.